# Changing style of label and tic separatly on marks on a gtk scale

Tags: css, gtk

Is it possible to style the tic and label of a mark on a GtkScale differently? How?

Here a the [docs from GTK](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html). I just started with GTK and are a bit lost here.

With the following CSS styling the color of the labels and the tics can be changed together:

```
.scale.mark {   
  color: red; 
}
```

Comment: Try `scale mark { color: blue } scale mark label { color: red; }`

Comment: Sadly, this does not work for me (GTK 3.18). Thx.

Comment: Hi! CSS syntax changed in Gtk 3.20. The above snippet is for Gtk >= 3.20.

Comment: I already tried > GtkScale mark label and different writings without success. Do you know if it is at least possible with 3.18? Documentation is missing here in notebook section https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.18/GtkNotebook.html

Answer (score 0):

```
//the other style class is scale-has-marks-below
// gtk version 3.18.9
GtkScale.scale-has-marks-above{
 color:red
 }
```

The above code will change the colour of marks to red.(it was tested on this code https://github.com/nobled/gtk/blob/master/tests/testscale.c)

when working with gtk CSS try using Gtk Inspector (https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/Inspector?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGTK%2B%2FInspector)

Comment: Thx. But to style the slider differently than the marks was not the question. I'd like to style the label and tick of a mark separatly with CSS. Any idea about that?

Comment: Thx for your advise for GTK inspector.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood you. I tried your suggestion and the label/text of the mark get the same color as the tick.

Comment: When adding marks you can use markup language to customize the color "<span color='blue' size='small'>Cold</span>", (By mark you mean the output of this gtk_scale_add_mark) and tick is the text above the slide (which shows the current value) right ? cause it seems to work for me .

Comment: You are right. With pango markup you can give the text of a mark an alternative style. About the definition: a mark has two objects 1) a little tick/ a small line which indicates where the mark is on the scale and 2) the text/label of that mark which is set with gtk_scale_add_mark. On newer GTK version than 3.18 it is possible to style that separatly without the use of pango markup. Because the different syntax of CSS in 3.18 I did not know how to do that. I think what you mean by tick is the value above the slider which changes when moving the slider, right?

Comment: yes, I thought the tick is the value above the slider. So you want to change the mark text color and also the mark indicator (the line which indicated the mark's position). i will see if it's possible.

Comment: Well I don't think its possible to change the color through CSS alone. you could try to use the markup to change the mark label color and use CSS to change the color of the mark indicator.

Comment: Oh, I know already that it is possible (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53SWLgo4Jps) - look between 12:30 and 13:30 - and you are right the word for tick is indicator. I just couldn't find out if this is working already with 3.18 versions. Thx for your effort.